# How to get values from grid view

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I have a gridview with editTexts as the individual views in it. I want to save the values that are in each of the editTexts because they are dissapearing when I switch to another fragment or press the home button, so how do I do that?

Would I need an array or arraylist that holds all of the views? How would I get the views if I did that?

fragment_score_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RedScorerFragment"
     >

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/gridLabel__red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/grid_label__red"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewRed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/gridLabel__red"
        android:columnWidth="40dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="7dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"

        >

    </GridView>


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

RedScorerFragment.java

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;

import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class RedScorerFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    LayoutInflater infl;
    GridView mGrid;

    EditText mText;

    int R1C1, R1C2, R1C3;

    View tView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        infl = inflater;
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score_red, container, false);
        mGrid = (GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewRed);

        tView = container.getRootView();


        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);

        /*mGrid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        });*/

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1");
            R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2");
            R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C3");

            Log.d("savedd R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
            Log.d("savedd R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
            Log.d("savedd R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
        }


        mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1", 0);
            R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2", 0);
            R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C3", 0);

            Log.v("saved R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
            Log.v("saved R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
            Log.v("saved R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
        }

        //Log.v("saved R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
        //Log.v("saved R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
        //Log.v("saved R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        //for(int i=0;i<mGrid.getChildCount(); i++)
        Log.v("Saving", String.valueOf(mGrid.getAdapter().getItem(0)));

        //Log.v("Saving", mGrid.getItemAtPosition(2).toString());
        Integer temp = (Integer) mGrid.getAdapter().getItem(0);
        int temp2;
        if(temp != null)
        {
            temp2 = temp;
            Log.v("temp2", String.valueOf(temp2));
            savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C1", temp2);
        }
        else
            Log.v("temp2", "Temp was null");

        mText = (EditText)tView.findViewById(R.id.weightedRed__red);
        Log.d("weighted Red", mText.getText().toString() );

        EditText oText = (EditText)tView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
        Log.d("red edit text", oText.getText().toString() );

        EditText lText = (EditText)tView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_blue);
        Log.d("blue edit text", lText.getText().toString() );

        //savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C2", (Integer) mGrid.getAdapter().getItem(4) );
        //savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C3", (Integer) mGrid.getAdapter().getItem(2) );

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View myView = convertView;
            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater li = infl;
                myView= li.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);

                EditText editText = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
            }

            return myView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 9;//only 9 
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }


    }


}
```

I tried changing the get Item method to

```
            @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return mGrid.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
```

but now it crashes when I press the home button and i get a stack overflow error

Comment: By default `EditText's` have values?

Comment: No I type something in them and then when i close it, it stores the values that were inputted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `TextWatchers`, you could simply add all your Editexts to an array, and then when you need your text from them, you could simply cycle through the array and call `getText().toString();` on all of them.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    EditText[] etCollection = new EditText[getCount()];

    public ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View myView = convertView;
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = infl;
            myView= li.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);

        }
        EditText editText = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red); 
        //^ moved to outside the null block
        etCollection[position] = editText;   
        return myView;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not shure if this is the absolute and eligant solution, but you can try to add to your adapter a value container (like a dataset) for all the `TextView`'s (it could be an ordinary `ArrayList` or somthing similar).

Then set a `TextWatcher` on every `EditText`:

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {...});
```

And change the value of the list item every time the `EditText` value is changed.

In you `onSaveInstanceState()` method all you need is to retrive the value from the adapter.

The rest I think is simple.

**Edit (Just to be clear)**

Your adapter should luck somthing similar:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// All the fancy stuff
List<String> dataset;

    @Override
    public View getView(...) {
        //... othe code
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));
    }

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    int index;

    public MyTextWatcher(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        dataset.set(index, s.toString());
    }

 }
 }
```

Comment: How would I get all of the `Edit Texts` though to add the `text watchers`?

Comment: Thanks i did it using the other answer's way